# Reshaping column values into rows with Identifier column at the end

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have measurements for Power related to different sensors i.e A1_Pin, A2_Pin and so on. These measurements are recorded in file as columns. The data is uniquely recorded with timestamps.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['12/12/2019', '12/13/2019', '12/14/2019', 
'12/15/2019', '12/16/2019'],
'A1_Pin': [2, 8, 8, 3, 9],
'A2_Pin': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'A3_Pin': [85, 36, 78, 32, 75]})
```

I want to reform the table so that each row corresponds to one sensor. The last column indicates the sensor ID to which the row data belongs to.

The final table should look like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['12/12/2019', '12/12/2019', '12/12/2019', 
'12/13/2019', '12/13/2019','12/13/2019', '12/14/2019', '12/14/2019', 
'12/14/2019', '12/15/2019','12/15/2019', '12/15/2019', '12/16/2019', 
'12/16/2019', '12/16/2019'],
'Power': [2, 1, 85,8, 2, 36, 8,3,78, 3, 4, 32, 9, 5, 75],
'ModID': ['A1_PiN','A2_PiN','A3_PiN','A1_PiN','A2_PiN','A3_PiN',                               
'A1_PiN','A2_PiN','A3_PiN','A1_PiN','A2_PiN','A3_PiN',
'A1_PiN','A2_PiN','A3_PiN']})
```

I have tried Groupby, Melt, Reshape, Stack and loops but could not do that. If anyone could help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tried `stack`, you were on one good track. you need to [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) after such as:

```
df2 = df1.set_index('DateTime').stack().reset_index(name='Power')\
         .rename(columns={'level_1':'ModID'}) #to fit the names your expected output
```

And you get:

```
print (df2)
      DateTime   ModID  Power
0   12/12/2019  A1_Pin      2
1   12/12/2019  A2_Pin      1
2   12/12/2019  A3_Pin     85
3   12/13/2019  A1_Pin      8
4   12/13/2019  A2_Pin      2
5   12/13/2019  A3_Pin     36
6   12/14/2019  A1_Pin      8
7   12/14/2019  A2_Pin      3
8   12/14/2019  A3_Pin     78
9   12/15/2019  A1_Pin      3
10  12/15/2019  A2_Pin      4
11  12/15/2019  A3_Pin     32
12  12/16/2019  A1_Pin      9
13  12/16/2019  A2_Pin      5
14  12/16/2019  A3_Pin     75
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
df1.set_index('DateTime').unstack().reset_index()
```